# Why WooCommerce API with same date_min, date_max returns 0 customers?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm making a simple API call to WooCommerce to get all the new customers on a daily basis.

If I set different date_min and date_max it works perfectly. For example: example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/reports/sales?**date_min=2022-02-26&date_max=2022-02-27**

For February 26th, I get 2 customers:

```
"totals": {
  "2022-02-26": {
    "sales": "338.20",
    "orders": 2,
    "items": 2,
    "tax": "60.99",
    "shipping": "0.00",
    "discount": "0.00",
    "customers": 2
  },
  "2022-02-27": {
    "sales": "364.65",
    "orders": 2,
    "items": 2,
    "tax": "65.76",
    "shipping": "0.00",
    "discount": "0.00",
    "customers": 0
  }
}
```

But If I set the same date_min and date_max customers return 0. For example example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/reports/sales?**date_min=2022-02-26&date_max=2022-02-26**

For February 26th, I get 0 customers:

```
"totals": {
  "2022-02-26": {
    "sales": "338.20",
    "orders": 2,
    "items": 2,
    "tax": "60.99",
    "shipping": "0.00",
    "discount": "0.00",
    "customers": 0
  }
}
```

What I'm missing?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: what do you get for 'date_min=2022-02-27&date_max=2022-02-27' - also 0?

Comment: out of curiosity (the [docs](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-sales-report) are not very specific) - what happens if you omit date_max?